# How I download file on FTP server in browser?

Tags: linux, ftp, ftp-server

I meet a issue when I build my FTP server .When I browse the directory on browser.I want to download the file when I click it rather than read it .How to implement this idea?

Comment: I built on Linux system.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to a HTTP server a FTP server does not provide a content type or content disposition information for the data, but only provides the plain data. This means that it is up to the browser to decide how to deal with the file. Browsers usually do this based on content and/or file extension, i.e. `*.txt`, `*.html`, `*.gif` etc get displayed inline while `*.bin` probably not.

Thus if you want to keep serving with FTP instead of HTTP you need to have the right content and file extension to make the browser download and not display the data. But again - the behavior depends fully on the browser, which means it might differ between browsers and might change when updating the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your file manager. There should be an option to open network places. There in the option of address or server address 
Enter your ftp server IP address

`ftp://<address of ftp server>/`

For example
`ftp://192.168.158.33/`

The you can just copy paste just like normal files

Or you could use the wget command to download the files using terminal .
`wget ftp://(address of ftp server)/(file location)`

Example 
`wget ftp://192.168.158.33/books/foo.pdf`

To download whole directory 
`wget -r ftp://192.168.158.33/books/*`

To download all the ftp directories and files in your ftp server

`wget -m ftp://192.168.158.33/`

I could onlu give tou more specific and exact answers once you completely tell us abt your situation that is what OS what windowmanager, which file manager etc.